# swig.exe not found: error when try install pylinkgrammar 0.2.14

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I get an error when I try to install pylinkgrammar 0.2.14, including:

> Building wheel for pylinkgrammar (setup.py) error:
> ...
> Command 'swig.exe' failed. No such file or directory
> ...
> Failed to build pylinkgrammar

[image: trace]

What can I do to resolve this error and get the installation done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install wheel using `pip install wheel`
Then download SWIG from here http://www.swig.org/download.html
and watch this video to know how to install it on windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDD9QqLtAws
and try to install pylinkgrammar again and it should work now

Answer (score 0):

Hye

I think you need to install this :
`pip3 install wheel`

Try again after doing it

Comment: i try this but it fail again

Comment: I have no solution, sorry

Answer (score 0):

- Download SWIG - http://www.swig.org/download.html
- Add Downloaded SWIG folder to PATH
- Restart Pycharm / any python coding environment
- Try to Install Again the packages

Answer (score 0):

**on macos** u can use **brew swig** in terminal, working good, tested on date, when im write it

what is brew: https://brew.sh/
swig on brew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/swig